# How do I get a specific form value in jquery using the parent $self click function

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form that looks something like this

```
<form action="#" class="ajax_form" method="post" id="comment_form" accept-charset="utf-8">
<textarea name="comment" id="form_comment"></textarea>
<input name="another_field" value="some data" type="text" id="form_another_field" />
<input name="method" value="some_method" type="hidden" id="form_method" />
<input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" id="form_submit" />
</form>
```

and a jquery submit listener for any class named ajax_form

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.ajax_form').submit(function() {

    alert(JSON.stringify($(this).serializeObject()));
    alert($("input:form_method").val());
    return false;
});
```

});

The first part of the submit function serlializes the form elements and puts them into a json string for an ajax request. But I need to extract the value of id #form_method before I make the ajax request but can't seem to figure out how to do it with reference to using $this. I tried getting the form children of $this but failed doing that as well.

Comment: Can't you simply use ID selector? `alert($("#form_method").val());`?

Comment: I should of specified that their may be multiple form elements with the id form_method on the same page so i have to select the correct one

Comment: ID's are supposed to be unique amongst the HTML elements. If they are repeating then you should use common class names instead of using same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `$("input#form_method").val()` instead of `$("input:form_method").val()`

In fact only `$("#form_method").val()` should perfectly do the job.

Eventually you may put specify the context of your search with `$("#form_method",this).val()` if you have multiple ajax_form on the page, but in such case you should reconsider using multiple time the same id as an id has to be unique

Comment: $("#form_method",this).val() was exactly what I needed thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the # in your selector. This should do the trick:

```
$("#form_method").val();
```

Comment: Yes that would work the only thing is there may be multiple forms per page so I need to grab the right value per form